# Angular multiple $http via json api

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, json

I am currently on a project that requires me to use angular to call in JSON data from a Rest API.

I am currently only able to pull in one table from MySQL DB. I am required to pull in 3 tables from 1 DB and display data from the tables in one table view on the client side.

3 APIs available via my restful service.

- rest/api.php/players
- rest/api.php/groups
- rest/api.php/teams

The code I have tried and tested will not work, but the below code is a working version of a single DB table.

the HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
    <button ng-click="myFunc()">Click Me!</button>

    <div ng-show="showMe">
        <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in myData">

            <td>{{ x.TeamID }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.TeamName }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.TeamGoals }}</td>

        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    </div>
```

And the angular:

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.showMe = false;
    $scope.myFunc = function() {
        $http.get("rest/api.php/teams").then(function (response) {
        $scope.myData = response.data.teams;
  });
        $scope.showMe = !$scope.showMe; 
    }
});
```

Comment: To understand what u wanted to achieve, u want to request data from 3 different tables from ur db and render it in one table view on the client side right? If so, were there other apis given to have that access or just one api that can perform the 3 pull from db and also note that rendering it on thesame table in the client side will need that the keys are of same type from the different db tables.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Yoyr question is not clear. I din't know if is 3 different tables in one db or 3 different tables in different dbs.  Please read about [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: If the question is how to make three asynchronous data requests and render a table once they all complete, you are looking for the [Angular $q all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) method.

Comment: Hi thanks for the replies, Unfortunately i failed with getting this to work. I resorted to using ajax/jquery to call in each table.